# Can we change Solaritas request handler, from Browse to Select?

Tags: search, solr

As we know if we go to localhost:8983/techproducts/browse we get Solaritas which search based on /browse in requestHandler. How to change search based on browse to be search based on /select for Solaritas search?

if you know it very helpfull for me
Thanks

Comment: I don't think that there are any differences between the two except for the fact that `/browse` presents everything in a human readable manner.

Answer (score 0):

Did You mean just like if go to link

> localhost:8983/techproducts/select

you want Solaritas to come up in browser is it. if that is the case just change request hander name in solrconfig.xml

But Solaritas is like demo UI, showing how we can use Solr response data to represent it to user on screen.